# Google Speech API with MRCP

Tags: java, speech-recognition, ivr, google-speech-api

Does some one know how to integrate Google Speech API as ASR with other IVR Systems e.g. Avaya, Genesis etc. These IVR/VXML systems generally integrate with ASR using MRCP protocol.

Comment: if you look at a sample system  https://github.com/yurifariasg/android-google-speech-sample/blob/master/GSpeechSample/app/src/main/java/me/yurifariasg/MainActivity.java#L91  (v1beta1 speech)  you can call this when you have byteArray from the microphone's stream.

Answer (score 3):

Integration of Google Speech API with atleast one IVR (Asterisk) is documented [here](http://zaf.github.io/asterisk-speech-recog/).

For the closed-source IVRs out there, dont think there is enough documentation or clarity on whether it is feasible for them to use Google Speech API since they only use MRCP, but there's a great discussion here on ideas of how to make that happen with a workaround (suggests creating modules that speak MRCPv2 with 3rd party services) :

https://github.com/RestComm/mediaserver/issues/284

and specifically, this comment: https://github.com/RestComm/mediaserver/issues/284#issuecomment-258404836

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Not all the IVR are limited by the protocol MRCP. The Voximal (VoiceXML browser for Asterisk) , integrate connector to Google Speech, Bing/Microsft and Watson/IBM speech Cloud API. The incrediblePBX OpenSource project integrates a module with Google Speeh too.